# PHP application is slowing down after making more than 4 requests

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, iis

I have a CodeIgniter PHP (5.3.13) application running on Windows Server 2008 on IIS7 and using MySQL as the data store.  After making more than 4 requests (for some reason) the application hangs, even when loading another session (new tab).    This application is used to run a simulation model (each scenario takes about 1 and 1/2 minutes to run on average).  I use an AJAX call ($.post) in order to call my controllers.

I already tried isolating the application using an application pool on IIS, but saw no change.

Would someone have an idea of what could possibly be happening.  I noticed that the performance of the application degraded over time.  I was able to run more than 4 sessions in the past.

UPDATE:
Ok, this is what I am doing. I tried to send background processes for each simulation and add a sleep() call while waiting for the process to be finished.  The is_process_running function simply check if the process has finished.  I am also getting some PHP blocking from the sleep() now apparently.  I am trying to understand what defines the maximum number of request that I can do before I start seeing the blocking. Is it a limitation with my server or a setting that I am missing in PHP?

```
$pid = $ssh->exec('cd /home/Projects/Model; kmodel -b ' . $runFile . ' >    run.out & echo $!');

while($this->is_process_running($ssh,$pid) == 3)
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: why not jam in some profiling writes to files (in append mode), maybe there are locking issues going on

Comment: Seems like my problem has to do with the fact that I am running the exec function from phpseclib and after four scenarios have been running, PHP slows down and makes me wait for one of those processes to finish before responding.  Is there some setting that would allow me to run more instances of the exec function in PHP?

Comment: What are you doing in that exec call that perhaps could be done without it? Sounds like a blocking call or something.

Comment: I am running a simulation model using the exec call.  I need to use it.

Comment: I was wondering why the 4 request limit.  After running 4 simulations, I see the blocking.  Is there any configuration change that I can do to make that limit higher?

Comment: I am seriously trying to help, but there is no information in your question for anyone to repeat what you are doing ... as you are not showing it

Comment: I appreciate your help Drew. Look at my update above.